# How to export a typescript function to be accessible from browser's command line?

Tags: typescript

```
var ident = (v: any) => {v};
export default ident;
```

It compiles succesfully, however if I try calling `ident` from the browser's command line it errors with:

```
VM1228:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ident is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: That works great, feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use function in browser console, you have to expose it first to window object.

Try this:

`(<any>window).ident = ident`